# Поразрядная сортировка(C++)

Tags: c++, сортировка

Суть проблемы в том, что компилятор зависает на выделеной строке

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int FindMax(int A[], int n)
{
    int max = A[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (A[i] > max) 
        {
            max = A[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

int FindDigit(int n, int i)
{
    int result = (n / pow(10, i - 1));
    result %= 10;
    return result;
}

int razryad(int n) 
{
    int N = n;
    int x = 0;
    for (; ; x++)
    {
        if (N < 1)
        {
            return x;
        }
        N /= 10;
    }
}

void Radix_sort(int A[], int n) 
{
    int max = FindMax(A, n);
    int razrad = razryad(max);
    int* result = new int[n];
    int* A1 = new int[n];
    int score[2][10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            score[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int cal = 1; cal <= razrad; cal++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            score[0][FindDigit(A[i], cal)]++;//считаем количество элементов в каждом разряде
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                score[1][i] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                score[1][i] = score[1][i - 1] + score[0][i - 1];//ищем стартовую позицию элемента 
            }
        } //до этой части всё работает
        for (int i = 0, a = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                for (; score[i][j] < score[1][j+1]; score[1][j]++)
                {
                    for (int z = 0; z < n; z++)
                    {
                        if (A[z] < 0)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (FindDigit(A[z], cal) == j)
                        {
                            A1[a] = A[score[i][j]]; //на этой строке вылет
                            a++;
                            A[score[i][j]] = -1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            A[i] = A1[i];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int *array = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        array[i] = rand() % 100;
        cout << array[i] << "| ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    Radix_sort(array, n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << "| ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: что значит "*компилятор зависает*"?  Если происходит вылет с какой-то ошибкой, приведите её текст, в котором скорее всего и будет ясно сказано, что у вас не так

Comment: от таких функций  и кода не только  компилятор, я тоже завис..

Answer (score 1):

Не смущает, что в `int razryad(int n)` благодаря `for (; ; x++)` цикл выполняется бесконечно? Компилятор при вызове этого цикла и крашится.

Comment: gitling, в студию вставь и попробуй. Я на бесконечный цикл и ожидал. Глупость попрошу не писать.

Comment: @CArtman, пробовал отладчиком пробежаться перед тем, как выложить этот вопрос?

Comment: @giting отладчик начинает грузить память процессора на выделенной строке, после определённого времени(не всегда одинаковый промежуток) вылетает без ошибки